# Increment a Counter Based off a Condition with a Sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to automatically increment a counter on a SELECT query based off some criteria.

There should be a counter that increases by 1 when the BatchID and Reference values changes.

Where the BatchID stays the same, it should use only 2 potential unique numbers, one for where there is a Reference value and another for where there isn't. I have added a column to the below sample data which has ExpectedResultCounter which shows what the result I expect.

I have managed to successfully get the numbering going with the following query:

```
select 
    NEXT VALUE FOR seqAutoNumber OVER (ORDER BY RowFilter) AS ID,
    *
from
(
    select
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BatchID, ContainsValue) AS RowFilter,
        ExpectedResultCounter,
        BatchID,
        Reference
    from
    (
        select CASE WHEN Reference is null then 1 else 0 END as ContainsValue, * 
        from   #Temp
    ) a
) 
b
order by 
    BatchID, 
    Reference
```

But I can't get the Sequence Number to match the same numbering as RowFilter with it sticking to the same number for the given circumstances. If I try PARTITION BY I get the following error:

```
Msg 11716, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
NEXT VALUE FOR function does not support the PARTITION BY clause.
```

Anyone have any ideas here? Is it even possible with a Sequence for it to re-use the same number? If not, what's a good way to get around this problem with a new set of numbers needing to be generated each time the query is run in not re-using previous numbers from a previous execution.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[seqAutoNumber] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 999999
 CYCLE 
 CACHE 
GO

Create Table #Temp
(
    Reference varchar(50) NULL,
    BatchID int,
    ExpectedResultCounter int
)

insert into #Temp
(
    Reference,
    BatchID,
    ExpectedResultCounter
)
SELECT 'P044276-8',21416,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E3723492-6',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A62723432-1',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P0402343250-4',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P2602348-4',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B0110662-2',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P3234977-7',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21419,3 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21419,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P382342391-1',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21419,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q234234234-3',21419,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E37234234-6',21468,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A6232432-1',21468,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P04023423450-4',21468,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'P2623432408-4',21468,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B0023423462-2',21468,4 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21468,5 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21468,5 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21468,5 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21468,5 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,21468,5

select * from #Temp
order by ExpectedResultCounter

drop table #Temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse a `SEQUENCE` number. And there are lots of limitations & restrictions on using it. You may refer to [NEXT VALUE FOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

One workaround for your requirement is to get the result into a temp table.

And then generate the ID based on grouping by BatchID and update back the temp table

```
update  t
set     ResultCounter = r.ID
from
(
      select   BatchID, ID = NEXT VALUE FOR seqAutoNumber OVER (ORDER BY BatchID) 
      from     #Temp
      group by BatchID
) r
inner join #Temp t  on  r.BatchID   = t.BatchID
```

EDIT 1 :

```
update  t
set     ResultCounter = r.ID
from
(
    select  BatchID, 
            RefIsNull = CASE WHEN Reference IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            ID = NEXT VALUE FOR seqAutoNumber OVER (ORDER BY BatchID) 
    from    #Temp
    group by BatchID, CASE WHEN Reference IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) r
inner join #Temp t  on  r.BatchID   = t.BatchID
                    and (
                            (r.RefIsNull    = 1 and t.Reference is null)
                        or  (r.RefIsNull    = 0 and t.Reference is not null)
                        )
```

Comment: Thanks, thought that was the case with a sequence number but good to have it confirmed. The problem with your update statement is that it doesn't take Reference into account, note the ExpectedResultCounter in my above query. Any options there you could suggest please?

Comment: How do you want the `Reference` to affect the sequence number ?

Comment: It's quite hard to explain in words which is why I gave the example, will try not to get tongue tied here :) Basically for each individual BatchID, the counter needs to stay the same for those that have a Reference value and a different counter that stays the same for those that don't have a Reference value. And this repeated for each BatchID as it goes forward using a Sequence value.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Squirrel, that's awesome. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're 99% there. Sometimes things have to be split out into multiple steps (sub-queries) to make SQL do what you want it to do.

The query below has the column `ExpectedResultCounter` which is based on your sample data, and a column `ResultCounter` being the end result of the logic in the query.

**Answer:**

```
select a.Reference
, a.BatchID
, a.ExpectedResultCounter
, b.ResultCounter
from #temp as a
inner join 
    (
    select distinct t.BatchID
    , iif(t.reference is null, 1, 0) as is_ref_null_flg
    , dense_rank() over (order by t.BatchId, iif(t.reference is null, 1, 0)) as ResultCounter
    from #temp as t
    ) as b
    on a.BatchID = b.BatchID
    and iif(a.reference is null, 1, 0) = b.is_ref_null_flg
order by b.ResultCounter
, a.Reference
```

**Update:**

In order to take advantage of the `sequence` object you've defined in the question, you would have to use the logic below. Your definition will take care of making sure you don't return the same `ResultCounter` values each time.

```
select c.BatchID
, c.is_ref_null_flg
, next value for dbo.seqAutoNumber over (order by c.ResultCounterPrelim) as ResultCounter
into #temp_step_one
from (
    select distinct t.BatchID
    , iif(t.reference is null, 1, 0) as is_ref_null_flg
    , dense_rank() over (order by t.BatchId, iif(t.reference is null, 1, 0)) as ResultCounterPrelim
    from #temp as t
    ) as c

select a.Reference
, a.BatchID
, a.ExpectedResultCounter
, b.ResultCounter
from #temp as a
inner join #temp_step_one as b on a.BatchID = b.BatchID
                              and iif(a.reference is null, 1, 0) = b.is_ref_null_flg
order by b.ResultCounter
, a.Reference
```

This modified answer was split into two queries, instead of using sub-queries, because the `next value for` syntax cannot be used in a sub-query (per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-restrictions)).

**Sidenote:** The `join` might be a bit rough on performance depending on the volume of data involved.

Comment: Thanks @Tarheel, that does the trick like my query, but how could I could incorporate a Sequence into it so I don't return the same ResultCounter values each time?